# How do I best model a turn-based board game as a State Machine in Java?

Tags: java, state-machine

I admit, I have a homework assignment to program a [board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mensch_%C3%A4rgere_dich_nicht) (Let's call it MEDN). I could do it in the simple stupid way, just have `nextPlayerTurn`, `winner`, etc, but I would really enjoy programming it as nicely as possible. However, I've been failing at coming up with how to implement such a State Machine so that it is easy to use to reflect my board game logic.

Let's say players can roll a dice, roll another time if they rolled a 6, and then after that make a move with one of the 4 figures, given certain conditions on the board.

My problems so far are:

- I can model the board easily, but which element of the machine is it? Is it part of the input, or is it the state? Am I going to output the new board as an output, or am I going to modify the current one in-place (which feels unclean to me). I will have to be able to determine all the possible moves a player can make, so maybe the first solution is better.
- The same process (roll, possibly re-roll, make a move) will be repeated for each player. If i was making a state machine on paper, I would make 3*4 states, each row for a player, each column for a step in this process. There must be some really nice way to do this in Java which I'd be excited to see. In addition to that, who the winner is has to be encoded as well.

I am failing to come up with a nice-looking solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

First I would say to stray away from trying to represent every state the game could possibly be in. Given a starting state, you can just compute what the next state will be based on the moves that the player makes. No need to map out every single possibility. (When creating an AI to play a board game, it is common to have it compute the next few possible board states, and choose a move based on that, rather than computing every possible board state because frequently that's impractical). In general, the states in the state machine would represent the state of the board. A player move would change the state of the machine and the terminating state would be a winning configuration.

That being said, I don't think a state machine is the best way to solve this problem. The "stupid simple way" can actually be the most elegant and clean way to code a game with very simple logic. It's not fancy, but trying to come up with a clever solution can over-complicate a simple problem.